# Is there anyway I can plot this graph using a wireframe surface?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, statistics

I am trying to plot a 3D graph using the code below. Is there any way I can use a wireframe surface, instead of the heatmap surface that I am using currently. Also, when I use the trisurf (what is currently in the code), some of the graph appears transparent? Does anyone know why?

```
def toy_g_2(sig):
   
    y_axis = np.linspace(4,0,100)

    x_axis = np.linspace(0,4,100)
   
    #calculate likelihood function

    toy_2_gaus = [(i, k, 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sig**2))*np.exp(-(1-i*k)**2/2*sig**2)) for i in x_axis for k in y_axis]
   
    #normalize
   
    post_test = []

    for e in toy_2_gaus:
        post_test.append(e[2])

    sum_of_z_val = sum(post_test)

    norm_z_val = []

    for e in toy_2_gaus:
        norm_z_val.append((e[0],e[1],e[2]/sum_of_z_val))
   

    #plot
   
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    col1 = list(zip(*norm_z_val))[0]
    col2 = list(zip(*norm_z_val))[1]
    col3 = list(zip(*norm_z_val))[2]
   
        
    # For prob density use:
    ax.plot_trisurf(col1,col2,col3,
                   cmap= 'viridis', edgecolor='none')
    ax.set_zlabel('probability density', fontsize=12, rotation = 0)
    ax.set_ylabel('b', fontsize=12, rotation = 0)
    ax.set_xlabel('a', fontsize=12, rotation= 0)
```